# Bernstein's probabilistic proof of Weierstrass's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> I propose to give a very simple proof of the following theorem of Weierstrass:
>
> 66 If $F(x)$ is any continuous function in the interval $\left[0,1\right]$ , it is always possible to
> determine a polynomial $E_{n}(x)=a_{0} x^{n}+a_{1} x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n}$ of degree $n$ high enough such that we have
> $$
> \left|F(x)-E_{n}(x)\right|<\varepsilon
> $$
> for every point in the interval under consideration. 99
>
> To this end, I consider an event $A$, whose probability is equal to $x$. Suppose $n$ experiments are conducted and that is agreed to pay a player the sum $F\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$, if the event $A$ occurs $m$ times. Under these conditions, the mathematical expectation $E_{n}$ for the player will have the value
> $$
> E_{n}=\sum_{m=0}^{m=n} F\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) \cdot C_{n}^{m} \cdot x^{m} \cdot(1-x)^{n-m} \tag{1}
> $$
> It follows from the continuity of the function $F(x)$ that it is possible to set a number $\delta$, such that the inequality
> $$
> \left|x-x_{0}\right| \leq \delta
> $$
> causes
> $$
> \left|F(x)-F\left(x_{0}\right)\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
> $$
> so that, if $\bar{F}(x)$ is the maximum and $\underline{F}(x)$ the minimum of $F(x)$ in the interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$, then
> $$
> \bar{F}(x)-F(x)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \quad F(x)-\underline{F}(x)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \tag{2}
> $$
> Let $\eta$ be the probability of the inequality $\left|x-\frac{m}{n}\right|>\delta$ and $L$ the maximum of $|F(x)|$ in the interval $[0,1]$
> We then have
> $$
> \underline{F}(x) \cdot(1-\eta)-L \cdot \eta<E_{n}<\bar{F}(x) \cdot(1-\eta)+L \cdot \eta .
>  \tag{3}$$
>
> But by **virtue of a theorem of Bernoulli**, we can take $n$ large enough to have
> $$
> \eta<\frac{\varepsilon}{4 L} \tag{4}
> $$
> Inequality (3) will in turn take the form
> $$
> F(x)+(\underline{F}(x)-F(x))-\eta(L+\underline{F}(x))<E_{n}<F(x)+(\bar{F}(x)-F(x))+\eta(L-\bar{F}(x))
> $$
> and so
> $$
> F(x)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}-\frac{2 L}{4 L} \varepsilon<E_{n}<F(x)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{2 L}{4 L} \varepsilon
> $$
> therefore
> $$
> \left|F(x)-E_{n}\right|<\varepsilon \tag{5}
> $$
> $E_{n}$ is clearly a polynomial of degree $n .$
> The theorem is therefore proved.
> I would only add two points.
> The approximate polynomials $E_{n}(x)$ are especially convenient, it seems to me, when you know exactly or approximately the values of $F(x)$ for $x=\frac{m}{n}(m=0,1, \cdots n)$.
> Formula (1) and inequality (5) show that, for any continuous function $F(x)$ :
> $$
> F(x)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=0}^{m=n} F\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) \cdot C_{n}^{m} \cdot x^{m} \cdot(1-x)^{n-m}
> $$
> S. Bernstein
>
> *Communications of the Kharkov Mathematical Society, Volume XIII*, 1912/13 (p 1-2) [refer](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/bernsteins-demonstration-du-theoreme-de-Weierstrass)

1. What is the idea behind equation $(3)$?
2. What theorem of Bernoulli is being used here?

Answer (score 2):

1. To get lower bound on expectation, we can replace our variable $E(x)$ with something smaller - specifically, with $\underline{F}$ on $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ and with $-L$ outside. Similarly for upper bound.
2. I think it's old name of [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Examples).

Comment: Can you explain the $\eta$ thing in 3?