# On the choice of Binomial distribution in Bernstein's probabilistic proof of Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm reading "Theory of Probability and Random Processes by Koralov and Sinai", in which there is Berstein's probabilistic proof of the famous Weierstrass Theorem.

*Statement of the theorem*

[image]

I interpret the construction of $\: b_n(x) \,$ as using $\: f \,$ as a random variable, and then find out $\: f(x) \,$ by calculating its expectation over a binomial distribution. My question:

1. why use binomial distribution as the distribution for $f$? Is it because we can interpret that $\: f \,$ gets its values through independent trials on $\: [0, 1]$?
2. My gut feeling is that we can use any "well-balanced" distribution that has only one peak, as far as the width of the peak shrinks to $0$ as $\: n →  ∞ \,$ (by "well-balanced" I mean the center of probability mass is at the peak of the probability distribution).

   Am i wrong? If so is there a proof that no other distribution works for the probabilistic argument?

Thanks!

Comment: I had very similar odubts: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485104/bernsteins-probabilistic-proof-of-weierstrasss-theorem

Comment: 2. only continuous functions can be approximated uniformly by polynomials.  Try to prove this converse direction yourself!

Comment: ah, of course, any uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions must be continuous... that was a silly question

Comment: Possible approach: Inspect the proof of the theorem and see exactly what properties of the binomial were used.